# Dojo 1.10. "closable Tabs" with StackContainer/StackController

Tags: dojo, widget

I am working with Dojo 1.10 and Dijit Widgets. Instead of using a TabContainer I need to use a StackContainer with a StackController. I can't find a way to make these "tabs" closable. Thought there would be a possibility comparable to the TabContainer, but I'm not able to figure out the solution.

I hope you can help me!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The child of the `stackContainer` should have a property `closable: true`.
Actually it should have all properties defined in `StackContainer.ChildWidgetProperties`. (see StackContainer.js code)
Then in the `stackController` you have to attach a click event (of a link for instance) to the method `onCloseButtonClick` (You can see how it is done in TabController.js code)

Comment: Thank you, @ben!
My problem is, there is no [x] symbol appearing in the button. If I look at it in the compiler the "closeButton" is set to "true". Also the ContentPane (child of the StackContainer) has a `closable: true` property.

Comment: As I said "you have to attach a click event (of a link for instance) to the method". TabController provides the close button but StackController does not. You have to create one.